# How can I avoid generating same expressions for commutative operators

Tags: python

I want to build a set of all possible expressions starting from a set of variables and operators. However, I do *not* want to generate both 'a+b' and 'b+a', as they are same, mathematically; while 'a/b' and 'b/a' are not.
I tried to differentiate the operators in commutative and non-commutative lists, but don't know how to write the commutative `for` loop which avoids degeneracy.

```
primary_descriptors=['a', 'b']
commutative_operators=['+', '*']
non_commutative_operators=['-','/']

b=[]

for x in primary_descriptors:
    for y in commutative_operators:
        b.append([x+y+z for z in primary_descriptors if z!=x])
d=[]
for x in primary_descriptors:
    for y in non_commutative_operators:
        d.append([x+y+z for z in primary_descriptors if z!=x])

flat_list_1 = [item for sublist in b for item in sublist] #from Alex Martelli's answer
flat_list_2 = [item for sublist in d for item in sublist]

print(flat_list_1)
print(flat_list_2)
```

The output of this code is

```
['a+b', 'a*b', 'b+a', 'b*a']
['a-b', 'a/b', 'b-a', 'b/a']
```

but I want ['a+b', 'a*b'] only in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the loop for commutative operators, run the outer loop for all operands, but the inner loop only for those later in the operands list.  Something like this, perhaps ...

```
for x_index, x in enumerate(primary_descriptors):
    for y in commutative_operators:
        b.append([x+y+z for z in primary_descriptors[x_index+1:] ])
```

New output:

```
['a+b', 'a*b']
['a-b', 'a/b', 'b-a', 'b/a']
```

Comment: Interesting answer, thank you. I will accept it soon. Aside: Can I make this better using iterators? I was trying, but could not figure out.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "better".  Yes, you could collapse each nested loop to a single statement ... but is that more readable?  Do you have so many operators that you need the speed increase?

Comment: Yes, I actually may have quite a few descriptors(~100) and operators (~10). That is why I was thinking about iterators.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `itertools` solution. `itertools.permutations` can be used to get all pairs in both orders whereas `itertools.combinations` can be used to get all pairs but only in one order:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, combinations
>>> primary_descriptors='abc'
>>> commutative_operators='+*'
>>> non_commutative_operators='-/'
>>> 
>>> [op.join(pair) for pair in combinations(primary_descriptors, 2) for op in commutative_operators]
['a+b', 'a*b', 'a+c', 'a*c', 'b+c', 'b*c']
>>> [op.join(pair) for pair in permutations(primary_descriptors, 2) for op in non_commutative_operators]
['a-b', 'a/b', 'a-c', 'a/c', 'b-a', 'b/a', 'b-c', 'b/c', 'c-a', 'c/a', 'c-b', 'c/b']
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to use the inequality operator, which will effectively prevent 'b' from being before 'a':

```
combinations = []
primary_descriptors=['a', 'b']
commutative_operators=['+', '*']
for x in primary_descriptors:
    for y in commutative_operators:
        combinations += [(x, y, z) for z in primary_descriptors if x <= z]
print(combinations)
```

Comment: I think I need only < as I am avoiding a*a , and also the combinations should be done with + not , . Then I have what I wanted. Thanks for the answer.